# How to pass the excel sheet dynamically to an excel source in ssis

Tags: excel, ssis

Sorry if the question is already asked

I'm new to ssis. I got a situation like, my package has to pick the excel files dynamically and should load them into database.so far i created a package for this,and set a variable to pick the file dynamically like...

**Variable name: File_Path ;Scope:Package; Data Type: String;**

**Value: C:\Today_IMPORT\New_Folder\calculation.xlsx**

But the problem is my excel sheet **calculation.xlsx** contains 4 sheets in it namely **Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3 and Sheet4**,my excel source has to pick the **Sheet2** every time my package runs.
i tried setting up the variable value to **C:\Today_IMPORT\New_Folder\calculation.xlsx\Sheet2** but its not working...

pls help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it always the second sheet and is it always named precisely "Sheet2"?   If so, see here http://sqlage.blogspot.com/2013/12/ssis-read-multiple-sheets-from-excel.html

Comment: Cant you add a fore-Each loop, Set it in such a way that progress to DFT, only if Sheet name = Sheet2. or Loop, in such a way that progress to DFT only on looping value = 2